# VS Code IntelliSense not working for Modules (PowerShell 5.1)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I know a lot of people are reporting various issues with vscode intelliSense and that the feature is buggy at best(?), but I'll still try to ask a question. Because - it has, for the most part, worked fine for me. Until I very recently tried changing some settings regarding the terminal, default terminal profile, behavior/visibility of the extension etc.

IntelliSense is still working for built-in cmdlets, but not for other modules. Even after explicitly importing the module and verifying the cmdlet exist, suggestions/auto-complete or whatever does not work. I should point out that this is only in the editor - in the terminal it works fine. Also, it seems to work (better) when using PS7, but I still rely heavily on PS5.

I tried reversing the changes I made to the settings, but alas no dice. Furthermore I cannot say with certainty it did work before I started messing with the settings, but I believe it did. I have, however, recently reinstalled my computer and also when I did so I installed the modules in my personal user-scope rather than the AllUsers (Program Files) scope - so there's a lot of factors and I don't know exactly what caused this... :-) But it worked not too long ago.

Just looking if anyone has any suggestions 'cause this is unbearable. TIA

[image]

[image]

My settings (I may have tested different variations and messed with both the commented settings and more...):

```
{
"git.autofetch": true,
"git.confirmSync": false,
"git.autoRepositoryDetection": false,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
"workbench.startupEditor": "none",
"workbench.list.openMode": "doubleClick",
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"editor.minimap.enabled": true,
"editor.cursorStyle": "line-thin",
"files.defaultLanguage": "powershell",

"powershell.promptToUpdatePowerShell": false,
"powershell.integratedConsole.focusConsoleOnExecute": false,
"powershell.integratedConsole.showOnStartup": false,
"powershell.integratedConsole.startInBackground": true,
"powershell.integratedConsole.suppressStartupBanner": true,
"powershell.startAutomatically": true,
"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": true,


// "powershell.scriptAnalysis.enable": true,
// "powershell.enableProfileLoading": true,
// "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
// "extensions.autoUpdate": true,
// "powershell.developer.editorServicesLogLevel": "Verbose",
// "editor.formatOnSave": true,
// "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
// "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
// "terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior": "default",
// "window.title": "${activeEditorLong}",
// "powershell.powerShellExePath": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
// "powershell.scriptAnalysis.settingsPath": "ScriptAnalyzerSettings.psd1",


// https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73845252/new-way-to-specify-powershell-7-in-visual-studio-code
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell5": {
        "overrideName": true,
        "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell",
        "color": "terminal.ansiYellow",
        "args": [
            "-NoLogo"
        ]
    },
    "PowerShell7": {
        "overrideName": true,
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell",
        "color": "terminal.ansiGreen",
        "args": [
            "-NoLogo"
        ]
    },
    "Command Prompt": null,
    "Git Bash": null,
    "JavaScript Debug Terminal": null,
    "PowerShell": null,
    "Ubuntu-18.04 (WSL)": null
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell5"
}
```

Comment: Did you try restarting the session (PowerShell: Restart Session command) after adding the module? Or just restarting VSCode in general. Also, why is that `Import-Module` statement so low in the screenshot?

Comment: I've tried both. The reason that `Import-Module` is so low is because I often don't explicitly import modules when doing some quick work ad-hoc. Instead I rely on auto-loading, which has been working fine for years. So something definitely changed. Nevertheless, even if I do import the module and/or restart the session and/or the application, the result is the same.